# How can I control YouTube playback with my keyboard hotkeys?

Tags: shortcut-keys, google-chrome, youtube, chrome-extension

Is there any way to control the video playback on YouTube through the special keyboard hotkeys of my laptop (e.g. Fn + F10/F11/F12)?

In case it is relevant, I am using Chromium as my web browser to access and play YouTube videos.

Comment: you could map the keys to the ones youtube uses. Those would e.g. be `k` for pausing or `SHIFT` + `N` for the next video in the playlist

Comment: Can you give an example how to map those?

Comment: On Windows, I would use AutoHotkey. It seems to me like the linux equivalent is called autokey, but I've never worked with it.

But on second thought, I might have misunderstood your question. You probably cannot control the video playback while it's in the background with the way I suggested - the window would need to be in focus. And if it is, then what speaks agains using the preprogrammed shortcuts?

Comment: If your intention was to control the video playback while your browser has focus but you're in a different tab (might also work outside of the browser but I don't suspect so) there are a few chrome extensions you could try.
e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamkeys/ekpipjofdicppbepocohdlgenahaneen or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/play-control-your-backgro/ggmbimncibjjccpgnfjacipbbnjadggg

Comment: Take a look to [my answer here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/139654/142171)

I've finally found an official post [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7631406?hl=en) with **Youtube** shortcuts, which also seems to work on Youtube Music.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Chrome extension [Streamkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamkeys/ekpipjofdicppbepocohdlgenahaneen) then configure the hotkeys in the options.

Only drawback: shortcut must contain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and use a letter or a number ; for other keys, some keys are accepted and some not (it doesn't work with <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>).

I just did it under Ubuntu 18.04 with Chromium 73.
 
You may be surprised by a black screen if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (finish reading the sentence before trying), you can come back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

L to fast forward, J to back forward and K to stop/play.

Comment: This only works with the Youtube browser tab in the foreground. It does not work when the browser is in the background and you work with another program. This is why there are the hotkeys on the keyboard. They (should) always work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [my answer here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/139654/142171)

> I've finally found an official post [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7631406?hl=en) with **Youtube** shortcuts, which also seems to work on Youtube Music.